# bluetooth could not be turned on hp laptop g6 2230tx the fn key along with the wireless button does not help

Tags: bluetooth

I am using ubuntu 14.04LTS on my hp pavillion g6 2230tx laptop. It supports a ralink driver. How do i get it working. Plz give me a step by step procedure..

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the Bluetooth software.

A guide [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) shows how.

Remember: Ctrl+Alt+T opens the terminal!